# Nitobi acquired by Adobe what does it mean to PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

When you visit phonegap http://phonegap.com/ it says Nitobi has been acquired by Adobe.

- What does it mean to developers who are using Phonegap to develop mobile apps?
- Will PhoneGap remain opensource?
- Will the PhoneGap development be Stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [blog](http://blogs.nitobi.com/andre/index.php/2011/10/03/nitobi-enters-into-acquisition-agreement-with-adobe/) for details.  Short answers to your three questions:

- The biggest impact to PhoneGap developers should be the proposed name change to Apache Callback
- PhoneGap will remain open source. Since it was MIT licensed, it would be impossible to close it. Adobe and Nitobi announced that PhoneGap will be open sourced at the Apache Foundation under the name Apache Callback
- Even though Nitobi started PhoneGap, much of PhoneGap development has recently come from other companies. For example, IBM makes most of the Android contributions. The acquisition will allow the former Nitobi employees to contribute even more to PhoneGap since they will no longer need to find consulting gigs.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the reply. so if I invest money in building apps using PhoneGap there will be support in the future from the open source community and I dont have to pay for using PhoneGap(I am not mentioning about the buildservice).

Comment: You'll never have to pay for using PhoneGap. I would expect the open source community to continue to support it, but like with any open source community, there are no guarantees or SLAs.